# Page Loading Multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, master-pages, pageload

Having a unusual problem with an application I'm building, so what I'm looking to do is a user can view preview of their adverts they have created, click the advert which is a dynamic link and be brought to a new page which will show the advert in more detail. The more detail page is then runs a to check the query string, pass the parameters of the query sting to a method which pulls the correct details form the database. This part works perfectly, but when the object is returned the pages loads again, calls the same method 3 times, but with null parameters which in returns a null reference to an object that doesn't exist.

I've tried to refactor the code so when a page loads it won't retrieve form the database unless the search parameters are valid. When the page loads, components won't work then, for example the Image Carousel.

I've tried hard coding the parameters into the method, will work perfectly. will only load once.

I've created two new pages which do not inherit form a master page and used the exact same methods. works perfectly. I tried the method on a two different pages that are inherited form the master page and same problem.

Detailed Page.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title=""  Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DetailAdvert.aspx.cs" Inherits="Lenders.ie.DetailAdvert" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="col-lg-9">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">


            <!--Advert Image -->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">



                    <!-- Carosel goes here -->
                    <div class="row carousel-holder">         

                       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10">
                                <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                    </ol>
                                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                                        <div class="item active">
                                            <img class="slide-image" id="Img1" runat="server" src="http://placehold.it/800x380" alt=""/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                            <img class="slide-image" id="Img2" runat="server" src="http://placehold.it/800x380" alt=""/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                            <img class="slide-image" id="Img3" runat="server" src="http://placehold.it/800x380" alt=""/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="right carousel-control"  href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--User Details-->
            <br />

            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">

                    <!-- Descriptin and profile view -->


                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                                <div class="well well-sm">
                                    <div class="row">



                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                            <img src="" runat="server" id="imgProfilePic" alt="" class="img-rounded img-responsive" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                            <h4>

                                            <asp:Label ID="lblFristName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblSecondName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

                                            </h4>

                                            <small><cite title="Location"><asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">
                                            </i></cite></small>
                                            <p>
                                                <i title="Email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                                <br />

                                                <i title="Join Date" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> <asp:Label ID="lblJoinDate" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />

                                                <i title="User Rating" class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"> </i><asp:Label ID="lblUserRating" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />

                                                <i title="Contact Number" class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"> </i><asp:Label ID="lblContactNumber" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

                                            </p>

                                            <!-- Split button -->

                                            <asp:Button ID="btnMessage" runat="server" Text="Message" CssClass="btn btn-success" />



                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                                <!-- Description / Product Details--> 
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                                <div class="well well-sm">
                                    <h4> Description: </h4>
                                    <p>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                    </p>

                                </div>
                            </div>



                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <!-- Comment Section -->

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10">
                        <div class="well well-sm">
                            <h4>Comments</h4>
                        </div>


                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>



        </div>

    </div>

</div> 



</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

**Detailed Aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using BLL;
using DataModels;


namespace Lenders.ie
{
    public partial class DetailAdvert : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public Advert_User ReturnedUserAdvet = new Advert_User();
        public BalAdvertManger BALMan = new BalAdvertManger();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            //Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);

            //GetData();
            //PopulatePage();

            //int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["UiD"]);
            //int AdvertID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["AdID"]);

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                GetData();          
            }



        }

        public void GetData()
        {
            //int UserID = 41;
            //int AdvertID = 2;

            int UserID = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["UiD"]);
            int AdvertID = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["AdID"]);

            if (UserID != 0 || AdvertID != 0)
            {
                ReturnedUserAdvet = BALMan.ReturnDetailedAdvert(UserID, AdvertID);
                PopulatePage();
            }

            //int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["UiD"]);
            //int AdvertID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["AdID"]);

            //int UserID = 41;
            //int AdvertID = 2;

            //ReturnedUserAdvet = BALMan.ReturnDetailedAdvert(UserID,AdvertID);


        }

        public void PopulatePage()
        {

        }


    }
}
```

This is where the link is and directs to the Detailed page.

Profile Page.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="false" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ProfilePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Lenders.ie.ProfilePage1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">


      <%-- Adverts View--%>

                    <asp:View ID="AdvertsView" runat="server">

                       <h2>Adverts</h2>

                    </asp:View>

       <%-- View Adverts --%>               

                    <asp:View ID="View_ViewAdverts" runat="server">

                        <h2>View Adverts</h2>

                        <div class="row">

                        <asp:Literal ID="Advert1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>

                        </div>


                      </asp:View>

<%--There was three closing divs here--%>


                    <asp:View ID="MessageView" runat="server">

                        <h2>Messages</h2>

                    </asp:View>


                </asp:MultiView>

              </div>

            </div>
         </div>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
```

**ProfilePage aspx.cs - Method that creates the link**

```
public void DisplayUserAdverts()
{
    int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
    int i = 0;

    ListOfUserAdverts = BalAdvertManager.ReturnUserAdvert(UserID);



    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
    {
        foreach (Advert item in ListOfUserAdverts)
        {

            string ColDiv = "col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4";
            string ThumbClass = "thumbnail";
            string Image = "AdvertThumbnails/" + item.Img1.ToString();
            string Caption = "caption";
            string Link = "DetailAdvert.aspx/?AdID=" + item.AdvertID.ToString() + "&UiD=" + item.UserID.ToString();
            Button btn = new Button();

            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, ColDiv);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);

            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, ThumbClass);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);

            //writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Src, Image);     

            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, Link);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A);

            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Src, Image);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Img);

            writer.RenderEndTag();

            writer.RenderEndTag();

            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, Caption);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);

            //writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Src, Image);

            //writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
            //writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, Caption);


            writer.RenderBeginTag("h4");

            writer.Write(item.Title.ToString());

            writer.RenderEndTag();

            writer.RenderBeginTag("p");

            //Does Something

            writer.Write(item.Desc.ToString().Substring(0, 50));



            writer.Write("</br>");

            writer.Write("Testing" + i.ToString());

            writer.Write("</br>");

            this.Controls.Add(btn);

            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, Link);
            //  writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A);
            writer.Write("Link");
            writer.RenderEndTag();

            writer.RenderEndTag();

            //writer.WriteBeginTag("p");

            //       // Does Something

            //writer.WriteEndTag("p");

            writer.RenderEndTag();

            writer.RenderEndTag();

            writer.RenderEndTag();

            i++;

        }
    }

    Advert1.Text = stringWriter.ToString();


}
```

Master Page.aspx

```
<%@ Master  Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="Lenders.ie.MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Shop Homepage - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core Content -->
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="Content/shop-homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> 
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button> 
               <%-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="www.google.com">
            </a>--%>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                       <asp:HyperLink ID="Home" runat="server">Home</asp:HyperLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="Services" runat="server">Services</asp:HyperLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="Contact" runat="server">Contact</asp:HyperLink>
                    </li>
                      <li>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="Login" runat="server">Log In</asp:HyperLink>
                    </li>


                </ul>
                <div class="navbar-form navbar-right">

                    <div class="input-group input-sm">

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm " AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>

                    <span class="
                    </span>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

         <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p class="lead">Shop Name</p>
                <div class="list-group">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" CssClass="list-group-item"  runat="server">Sports</asp:HyperLink>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" CssClass="list-group-item"  runat="server">Hobbies</asp:HyperLink>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" CssClass="list-group-item"  runat="server">Life Style</asp:HyperLink>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" CssClass="list-group-item"  runat="server">Another Example</asp:HyperLink>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" CssClass="list-group-item"  runat="server"> Blah </asp:HyperLink>
                </div>
            </div> 

<%--            <div class="col-md-9">

                <div class="row carousel-holder">

                    <div class="col-md-12">--%>


        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">



        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

                        </div>
                         </div>


              <%--      </div>

                </div>

             </div>--%>

             <div class="container">

        <hr>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>enter code here
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Master Page.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Lenders.ie
{
    public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your masterpage remove everything after </html>

Comment: Sorry bad crop, there is nothing after </html> @kami